# Oracle calendar with holidays

Tags: oracle, date, calendar

I'm trying to build a calendar, which appears to be working okay. How can I include a holiday column with 'Y' for a holiday and a 'N' if not a holiday.

In my test CASE below I want Feb 8 holiday 'Y' and all other rows =''N'

```
CREATE TABLE holidays (holiday_date) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '39' DAY FROM DUAL

with calendar as (
        select rownum - 1 as daynum
        from dual
        connect by rownum <= to_date('28-feb-2023') - to_date('1-feb-2023') +1
    )
select to_date('1-feb-2023') + daynum as monthdate
from calendar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is `holidays` table's purpose as it contains only one row; then, you have a CTE (not *perfect*, though - if you use `to_date`, then apply format model as well) for February 2023, and it doesn't use previously created `holidays`.

Anyway: a simple option is to create `calendar` *as is* (for example, for year 2023, up to *today*) and include `cb_holiday` column (`cb` as *checkbox* whose value is Y or N) which is N by default, and updated later for desired dates.

```
SQL> create table calendar (datum, cb_holiday) as
  2    select trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + level - 1, 'N'
  3    from dual
  4    connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + 1;

Table created.

SQL> update calendar set
  2    cb_holiday = 'Y'
  3    where datum in (date '2023-02-08');

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From calendar
  2  where to_char(datum, 'yyyymm') = '202302'
  3  order by datum;

DATUM     C
--------- -
01-FEB-23 N
02-FEB-23 N
03-FEB-23 N
04-FEB-23 N
05-FEB-23 N
06-FEB-23 N
07-FEB-23 N
08-FEB-23 Y       --> here it is
09-FEB-23 N
10-FEB-23 N
11-FEB-23 N
<snip>
26-FEB-23 N
27-FEB-23 N
28-FEB-23 N

28 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you don't want to `update` table in a separate statement, yes - you can do it in `create table` using e.g. `case` expression:

```
SQL> create table calendar (datum, cb_holiday) as
  2    select trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + level - 1,
  3      case when trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + level - 1 in (date '2023-02-08') then 'Y'
  4           else 'N'
  5      end
  6    from dual
  7    connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + 1;

Table created.
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The 1 row was just to keep my example succinct. Sorry I didn't make that point clear. I'm looking for a generic solution without hardcoded VALUES such as the feb 8. Something that could be built on the fly each time, if that is possible? Maybe something with if EXISTS in a case statement???

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, of course, you can use CASE expression if you want. I edited the answer which shows how to do it. Even if you don't want to literally create table but use a CTE, you'd do the same; no difference. Though, in my opinion, it is a better option if you have a *physical* table as it can be indexed for better performance and used in any query that needs a calendar. If you choose to use a CTE, then you have to use it in **every** query, and then that's not *funny* any more but tedious.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table calendar (dt, holiday) as
      select trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + level - 1,
        case when trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + level - 1 in ( select  holiday_date
     from  holidays
      )   then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end
      from dual
      connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'yy') + 1;
```